# why no overflow warning when converting int to char

Tags: c, visual-c++

```
int i=9999;  

char c=i;
```

gives no overflow warning, While

```
char c=9999;
```

gives,

> warning C4305 initializing  truncation from int to char

why no overflow warning when converting `int` to `char`?

Comment: @pmg: No, they're both initializations.

Comment: You're right @KeithThompson, thank you. I deleted the wrong comment.

Comment: @pmg That comment of yours confused me so much that I had to post it in a separate question.This is what you had said--`It's not the same thing. The first is an assignment, the second is an initialization`.And here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500028/how-is-int-i-999-char-c-i-different-from-char-c-999

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture: sorry about that.

Comment: @pmg Actually,StackOverflow plebs like me don't expect **ANY** mistakes from the aces like you,with 25k+ reputation..LOL..

Comment: This one was a biggie. I hope I don't have many more biggies "floating around". I'm glad it was caught and can do no more harm.

Comment: @pmg Actually I saw no reason to doubt your comment.So I had taken that down in my notebook for C nearly 2 months back.I was even revising that yesterday when it occurred to me **how come** one is an initialization and other is a declaration.So to clarify it I posted it as a question.Never knew so much facts would come out of it.In fact,many guys voted to close my question thinking it's a duplicate.Luckily others like Keith saw what I intended to ask.

Comment: Additional answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318398/c-assigning-an-int-to-a-char-why-does-this-work-without-at-least-a-warning

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll get [warning C4244](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/th7a07tz(v=vs.110).aspx) when compiling with /W4 (which you should **always** do).

> warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from '`int`' to '`char`', possible loss of data

Comment: :( I forgot to enable the highest warning.
Thanks

Comment: Note that that warning doesn't take into account the fact that the value of `i` happens to be `9999`. The compiler would probably issue the same warning for `int i = 42; char c = i;`

Answer (score 1):

Whether *any* code construct produces a warning is up to the cleverness of the compiler and the choices made by its authors.

```
char c=9999;
```

`9999` is a constant expression. The compiler can determine, just by analyzing the declaration with no additional context, that it's going to overflow. (Presumably plain `char` is signed; if it's unsigned, the conversion is well defined -- but a compiler could still choose to warn about it.)

```
int i=9999;  

char c=i;
```

This has the same semantics, but for a compiler to warn about the initialization of `c`, it would have to know that `i` has the value `9999` (or at least a value outside the range of `char`) when it analyzes that declaration.  Suppose you instead wrote:

```
int i = 9999;
i = 42;
char c = i;
```

Then clearly no warning would be necessary or appropriate.

As [James McNellis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10503469/827263) indicates, a suffiently clever compiler *can* warn about either case if it performs additional analysis of what's going to happen during the execution of the program. For some compiler, it helps to enable optimization, since the analysis required to optimize code (without breaking it) can also reveal this kind of potential run-time error.

I'll note that this is an answer to the question you asked: why is there no warning. The answer you accepted is to the *implied* question: "I *want* a warning here; how can I enable it?". I'm not complaining, just observing.

Comment: +1. **pmg** too admitted the comment about one being an initialization and other being an assignment was wrong.Now the whole thing is very clear.Thanks for the time it took to come up with 2 fine answers.