# How is {int i=999; char c=i;} different from {char c=999;}?

Tags: c

My friend says he read it on some page on SO that they are different,but how could the two be possibly different?

**Case 1**

```
 int i=999;
 char c=i;
```

**Case 2**

```
 char c=999;
```

In first case,we are initializing the integer `i` to `999`,then initializing  `c` with `i`,which is in fact `999`.In the second case, we  initialize `c` directly with `999`.The truncation and loss of information aside, how on earth are these two cases different?

**EDIT**

Here's the link that I was talking of

[why no overflow warning when converting int to char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503434/why-no-overflow-warning-when-converting-int-to-char)

One member commenting there says --**It's not the same thing. The first is an assignment, the second is an initialization**

So isn't it a lot more than only a question of optimization by the compiler?

Comment: if you are using clang, you can use the emit llvm option with -s... the llvm is more readable that platform dependent asm... if I had my computer out I would do a couple of tests, but in any case the more interesting thing than the code will be how the platform you are on handles the overflow of your 8 bit value...

Comment: Check the edit please that I have added.

Comment: If you have a question about the answer there, you should ask it there, not open another question.

Comment: @JimBalter I'll keep that in mind Mr.Balter.But I really felt that the nature of both questions are different.I want to know something other than what the OP there asked.

Comment: If you "want to know something other than what the OP there asked," you should let us know what that "something" is.  Unless you can articulate that this is just a duplicate, because the answer to "what is different" is...  the original question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why no overflow warning when converting int to char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503434/why-no-overflow-warning-when-converting-int-to-char)

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate.

Comment: @djechlin Looking at the grand answers I got,I don't regret posting this question.

Comment: @KeithThompson can you edit the question to make it more clear what it is asking, apart from what is supplied in the proposed dupe?

Comment: @djechlin: It seems clear enough already. The other question specifically asks why there's a warning in one case but not the other. This is a more general question, asking what is the difference, if any, between the two constructs. One can imagine, in a language similar but not identical to C, that there could be real semantic differences between them beyond the presence or absence of a warning.

Comment: @KeithThompson them I'm voting to close as duplicate on the grounds that it's answered under "why does one produce a warning but not the other"?

Comment: @djechlin: The answer to the other question is that there is a difference, based on the (optional) behavior of a particular compiler. The answer I posted to this question emphasizes the fact that there is no *semantic* difference, something that the other question didn't ask about.

Comment: It's amusing the Keith provided very similar answers to both. I consider them effectively dups and will vote accordingly.

Comment: @JimBalter: Look at the last sentence: "So isn't it a lot more than only a question of optimization by the compiler?". The OP of this question is specifically asking about issue that the other question did not cover. The answer just happens to be that there is no semantic difference, but that doesn't make a "what's the difference?" question either invalid or a duplicate.

Comment: @KeithThompson The OP added that sentence in response to David Grayson's irrelevant answer; the other question didn't ask about generated code either, so that sentence is irrelevant to the point.

Comment: **pmg** took back that comment of his hours back.Now it's all clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They have the same semantics.

The constant `999` is of type `int`.

```
int i=999;
char c=i;
```

`i` created as an object of type `int` and initialized with the `int` value `999`, with the obvious semantics.

`c` is created as an object of type `char`, and initialized with the value of `i`, which happens to be `999`. That value is implicitly converted from `int` to `char`.

The signedness of plain `char` is implementation-defined.

If plain `char` is an unsigned type, the result of the conversion is well defined. The value is reduced modulo `CHAR_MAX+1`. For a typical implementation with 8-bit bytes (`CHAR_BIT==8`), `CHAR_MAX+1` will be 256, and the value stored will be `999 % 256`, or `231`.

If plain `char` is a signed type, and `999` exceeds `CHAR_MAX`, the conversion yields an implementation-defined result (or, starting with C99, raises an implementation-defined signal, but I know of no implementations that do that). *Typically*, for a 2's-complement system with `CHAR_BIT==8`, the result will be `-25`.

```
char c=999;
```

`c` is created as an object of type `char`. Its initial value is the `int` value `999` converted to `char` -- by exactly the same rules I described above.

If `CHAR_MAX >= 999` (which can happen only if `CHAR_BIT`, the number of bits in a byte, is at least 10), then the conversion is trivial. There are C implementations for DSPs (digital signal processors) with `CHAR_BIT` set to, for example, 32. It's not something you're likely to run across on most systems.

You may be more likely to get a warning in the second case, since it's converting a constant expression; in the first case, the compiler might not keep track of the expected value of `i`. But a sufficiently clever compiler could warn about both, and a sufficiently naive (but still fully conforming) compiler could warn about neither.

As I said above, the result of converting a value to a signed type, when the source value doesn't fit in the target type, is implementation-defined. I suppose it's conceivable that an implementation could define different rules for constant and non-constant expressions. That would be a perverse choice, though; I'm not sure even the DS9K does that.

As for the referenced comment "The first is an assignment, the second is an initialization", that's incorrect. Both are initializations; there is no assignment in either code snippet. There is a difference in that one is an initialization with a constant value, and the other is not. Which implies, incidentally, that the second snippet could appear at file scope, outside any function, while the first could not.

Answer (score 2):

Any optimizing compiler will just make the int `i = 999` local variable disappear and assign the truncated value directly to `c` in both cases. (Assuming that you are not using `i` anywhere else)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more please.

Comment: Just to elaborate a little on what @Jack said, he means that the compiler will most likely just destroy your `i` value. Meaning the variable will never exist after compilation and thus `c=999` will be the only thing that exists meaning `case 2`. However, if you are using the `i` variable else where in your code down the line then the compiler will keep `i` and `c` like your case 1 and continue down the path.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your compiler and optimization settings.  Take a look at the actual assembly listing to see how different they are.  For GCC and reasonable optimizations, the two blocks of code are probably equivalent.

Comment: Some more elaboration please.OP is not very smart.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture Run it using `gcc -S` and compare listings.

Comment: Bad answer. The question isn't about the generated code, it's about the semantics, which are defined by the language standard.

Comment: In the original question all he really asked is "how on earth are these two cases different?" so you shouldn't be so sure about that, Jim Balter.

Comment: "so you shouldn't be so sure about that" -- Even though the subsequent discussion makes it very clear that I was right? It was clear from the start that the question wasn't whether they might generate different code.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that the first also defines an object `i`of type `int`, the semantics are identical.

Comment: So what the user **pmg** from that link said is wrong?Since he seems a reputed user I had to confirm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503434/why-no-overflow-warning-when-converting-int-to-char

Comment: @JimBalter: Given `char c = 999;`, a compiler is not required to determine that there's an overflow or to warn about it. It could generate code that evaluates the expression `999` in type `int` and converts it to `char` at execution time. That's exactly what happens in the semantics of the abstract machine. Doing the conversion at compile time is an optional optimization.

Comment: "So what the user pmg from that link said is wrong?" -- Well, obviously his comment was wrong, since they are obviously both initializations. That's a different matter from whether they are different though; obviously, they are different enough that the compiler used issued a warning for one but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

> i,which is in fact 999

No, `i` is a variable. Semantically, it doesn't have a value at the point of the initialization of c ... the value won't be known until runtime (even though we can clearly see what it will be, and so can an optimizing compiler). But in case 2 you're assigning 999 to a char, which doesn't fit, so the compiler issues a warning.

Comment: YESSSS!!That's the word,**Overflow**.Can you kindly elaborate Mr.Balter..a little more details for easy understanding.

Comment: I'm just saying that 999 can't fit into an 8 bit char so the compiler warns about it. An int (i) may or may not fit, depending on its value at runtime, so the compiler doesn't warn about it (despite the fact that we can all see that the value will always be 999).

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no "compile-time overflow" in either case.  Logically, the initialization happens at run time. The compiler may be able to do more compile-time analysis in one case than in the other, but it's not required to do so. A sufficiently simple-minded compiler needn't warn about `char c = 999;`.

Comment: It's entirely possible that a compiler will issue a warning for one but not the other, but a sufficiently clever compiler can warn about both, and a sufficiently naive (but still conforming) compiler can warn about neither.

Comment: @KeithThompson The calculation of the value of the initializer is done at compile time ... it is `(char)999`.

Comment: "A sufficiently simple-minded compiler needn't warn" -- I never said that the compiler is required to issue a warning, I'm just explaining why this compiler does so. "a sufficiently clever compiler can warn about both" -- It would have to be so clever as to combine flow analysis with parsing.

Comment: @JimBalter: A particular compiler can certainly evaluate it at compile time. But a compiler can also evaluate `int i = 999; char c = i;` at compile time -- or eliminate both declarations altogether if they have no effect. The conversion of `999` from `int` to `char` and the conversion of `i` from `int` to `char` are *both* logically run-time operations that can *optionally* be evaluated at compile time. One just requires a little more cleverness than the other.

Comment: There are cases where a compiler is required to evaluate certain expressions at compile time, such as `int arr[2+2];`. This is not one of them.

Comment: @KeithThompson Non sequiturs / strawmen. "One just requires a little more cleverness" -- No, it requires a quite different and more difficult to achieve compiler organization than is common with extant compilers.

Comment: Aside from all that, @KeithThompson provided an excellent, complete answer and the OP ought to accept it.

Comment: @JimBalter When you say that the conversion of 999 to `char` is done at compile time, is that a practical observation [every compiler does it] or is it something the standard demands? If the latter, can you point me to the section?

Comment: I need new spectacles then. Mine don't show me what's between the lines ;)

Comment: @JimBalter: Try compiling with `gcc -O3`. For `int i = 999; char c = i; printf("c = %d\n", c);`, it passes a constant `-26` to `printf`. It does the of the (non-constant) `i` from `int` to `char` at compile time, so it certainly *could* warn about it. Apparently it just chooses not to.

Comment: @JimBalter: "Apparently it just chooses not to" is verbal shorthand for "Apparently the compiler's authors chose not to write it so it does so". (FYI, I used to work on compilers for a living.) The difference between warning about one case and warning about the other is a only a difference of degree. Optimizations can be done by any phase of the compiler; some simple optimizations are done by default even if the optimization phase isn't invoked. And yes, increasing optimization can often enable additional warnings.

Comment: @JimBalter: If you're going to insult me, I will not discuss this with you any further. Anyone else who's interested might want to look into [data-flow analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis). Compilers can and do generate code and/or emit warnings based on compile-time analysis of how a program will behave during execution.